# How to add a 'Sum' column in a DataGrid?

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, datagrid

I need to add some columns in the DataGrid view at run time.

I have nearly 12 columns in the DataGrid and I need to add 5 columns fully from top to bottom and show the sum result at last column.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Is this Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: I had Created a Table in SqlDatabase Inside the Vb.net and its a Datagrid View Option I Had Retrived a Data From That Table With a Criteria of the Selected Person I Just Need Now Is To Sum Up Only the 5th Column Data From Top Till The Last Line And Print The Answer Can You Understand sir.....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a DataSet (ds) to fill the DataGrid:

```
Dim sumCol As DataColumn
sumCol = New DataColumn("Total", GetType(Double))
sumCol.Expression = "ColumnA + ColumnB + ColumnC + ColumnD"  ' replace by the actual column names'
ds.Tables("TableName").Columns.Add(sumCol)
```

**EDIT**

This code calculates the sum for each row and adds a column.

If you want to calculate the sum of a column you will need to iterate over the rows and display the result yourself. You should not add that result as a row because you can only have a single type of row in a DataTable. A DataGrid is not a spreadsheet.

There are [third party grids that allow you to add such features](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHDTILFY-Vk)

Comment: Emo, if you add an apostrpohe @ the end of your line of comments (code line #3), it will allow the fourth line to be rendered as pretty text. It's a bug in the markup. great answer btw.